Secondary Dominant Harmony vs Diatonic Melody
I am trying to understand the application of secondary dominant harmony by studying its effects on the famous song, Do-Re-Mi from the Sound of Music.
I have come up with this, which sounds great - but I honestly cannot tell the difference between this and the more humble diatonic version.
The minor chords ii and iii sounded more "muddy", though - which is less in line with the mood of the original score.
I am not even sure which version Julie Andrews actually sang in the MV shared above.

Please re-post this in The Auditorium, which is dedicated to this purpose.

I am interested in understanding the non-diatonic notes in the melody, in relation the the harmony.

Are you genuinely unable to tell the difference between the two scores, even after listening to them consecutively?

@Dekkadeci FYI: There's a current discussion in the chat room.

This is a video I used to get both audio and the score...



From your comments in the chat room it seems your question is mostly about whether the song was meant to teach solfege and whether an untrained singer would have any awareness there are non-diatonic pitches in parts of the song.
First, we should address what I think is your assumption that solfege means diatonic. That is natural to assume, because solfege is often presented in the context of just a simple, diatonic major scale, but you should be aware there is solfege for chromatic pitches.
The full song from the movie is kind of in the old verse/chorus form (although in my linked video the opening "verse" isn't labelled as such, and the "chorus" is labelled "refrain." Anyway, the entire opening "verse" section is in fact entirely diatonic. In that regard the verse presents no dilemma for solfege and diatonicism.
Most importantly, what I notice is that all lyrical syllables that are explicitly solfege syllables in the verse, and the references to solfege by puns in the refrain, are diatonic pitches, and are correctly matching syllables with pitch according to moveable do solfege. In other words, the singer who might learn solfege from this song will in fact only sing diatonic pitches with correct solfege syllables.
I think that leaves only the question whether the accompaniment using secondary dominants for roughly the second half of the refrain would confuse the singers sense of learning solfege? I say "no" for one simple reason. I have several solfege method books and they use secondary dominant harmonies in their accompaniments early in the lessons. I have one that does as soon as the second lesson!

She sang the first version, with the secondary dominants.   The second version is, I suppose fine as far as it goes, but it isn't what Rodgers wrote or what Andrews sang.   Have you been agonizing over these for so long that you can't hear which is authentic?  That can happen!  :-)
Not sure what more there is to 'understand'.   The tune uses some chromatic harmonies.  You have correctly described them as 'secondary dominants'.
